# Iframe-curl content theft

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, nginx

My Internet site opens and indexes in a different domain.
I think Those who are using curl, because when I block access to my site IP addresses, the thief gives error about the field name curl.

However, at certain intervals the same thing is done with different IP addresses

On my Own site;

I'm using Wordpress
Panel VESTACP

As an Example I can give the following site the same situation same person does me

Real site:

http://uptodown.com/android

Thief site:

http://pill.pl/android

What can I do to prevent it?

Comment: you might want to try to rephrase the upper part of your question, i dont quite understand it. and, i don't see any iframe on the apkpure page.

Comment: hey, I've added a better example

Real site:

http://uptodown.com/android

Thief site:

http://pill.pl/android

Comment: If all they're doing is scraping your pages and re-hosting it, nothing. You can try rudimentary things like blocking non-browser user agents but anyone worth their salt would circumvent that easily, you could try using cloudflare to make sure they're real users first, but at the end of the day there's noting to stop someone from copying your pages HTML and putting it on their site.

Comment: i understand

well, nginx only one domain works possible?

different url connection block, so image, javascript, etc

Comment: It's hard to prevent but after-the-fact you can complain. If in the US file a DMCA takedown notice with their webhost. Tell Google about the duplicated content (lots of search search results for "report a site to google for copying content").